# In the NXT register alias dialog pop up, what is the DEADLINE text field for?

Tags: nxt, alias

What is the deadline text field for in NXT register alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deadline field is the amount of time in minutes/blocks (1440, or one day being the default) for the transaction to complete. If it is not completed in that time period you receive a "refund" from the network and the alias will not be registered to you.

A common mistake is to set the deadline to 10, or an even lower number reducing the odds of your transaction going through.